# Compressing web service request

Tags: c#, web-services, gzip

I have a webservice and client in c#/dotnet and I am using EnableDecompression to gzip compress the responses that I get from the web server.  Is it possible to compress the requests as well?

Comment: Are you pushing large data up in your request?  If not, compression might cost you more than it will gain you.

Comment: Yes, we are trying to push up about 150MB of data in about 100 batches of 1.5MB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP extensions allow you to monkey with the SOAP stream on both the client and server. They're nice because you can leave your service code alone - manipulation occurs before a webmethod begins and after it ends. They work a lot like an HttpModule but can be included on the client/request side as well.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx
- [SOAP Message Modification Using SOAP Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/esw638yk(v=vs.100).aspx)

Other than that, the only option that comes to mind is manually serializing and compressing large SOAP elements as byte[], then manually decompressing and deserializing on the server (shudder...). The maintenance issues with this approach are likely prohibitive.

Comment: It looks like your 3rd link is just being redirected to http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/?id=SOAPExtensions

Comment: @Zack - Yeah, the answer is almost six years old (!) and suffered from link rot. I replaced the bad link with a Microsoft article. Beware, SOAP extensions are not part of WCF and are therefore largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this tutorial](http://www.infosrama.com/soapcompression.htm) on compressing SOAP messages in C#, using the SharpZipLib library and SOAP extensions:

Seems to garnish about a 30% compression, will be giving this a try today.

Comment: Archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20060507182910/http://www.infosrama.com/soapcompression.htm