# ASP Response.Flush() flushes partial data

Tags: asp.net, iis, flush

I am developing a web app with an ASP server side and I use an iframe for data push.

An ASP handler flushes every once in a while some javascript to the iframe:

```
context.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>top.update('lala');</script>");
context.Response.Flush();
```

My problem is that sometimes, when I receive the data, I don't get the full text.
For example I will receive this : `<script language='javascript'>update('lala');</`
Unfortunately this prevents the javascript code from being executed if no other data is to come during the next second or so.

One workaround I have is to have a thread flushing '..........' every 500ms. (Then I will receive `script>......` which will complete my javascript.)

However I am sure there must be a way to have Response.Flush() sending the whole chunk of data. 
Does someone have an idea on how to use properly Response.Flush() ?

Thank you!

Charles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my coworkers figured out the problem. Gzip compression was enabled on IIS, which was preventing the web browsers getting full chunks of data.

Among the solutions:

**Disable compression for all websites:**

For IIS 5.1, go to `Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Internet Information Services`. Right click on `Web Sites`, click on `properties` and remove the ISAPI filter `Compression`.

For IIS 7, go to `My Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationHost.config` and change the part `httpCompression` so that compression is not enabled for your particular page.

**Disable compression just for your website:**

In the `web.config` file of your application, add the line `<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false"/>` under the section `<system.webServer>`.

**Disable compression for a particular web page or a particular request**

These good guys found a way to do it:

[Can gzip compression be selectively disabled in ASP.NET/IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656332/can-gzip-compression-be-selectively-disabled-in-asp-net-iis-7?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you use gzip compression ratio up to 3, IIS serves chunked page. And there is no significant difference between gzip ratio 3 and 9. [Look at IIS compression ratio test](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx)