# Classic ASP Intentional Wait / Delay inside Loop with Buffer Flushing

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

We have a script that sends emails and we want an intentional wait for `n` milliseconds between messages to not flood the server.  The `asp_Wait()` I found works but without any output.  That is, when the script is completely done running it dumps to the page.

My goal is to view each line in a browser as it is executed so I can monitor the progress of the script.

I have tried both with buffering ON and OFF with the same curious result (Server 2008 R2, IIS7).  A test loop demonstrates this with a 1-second delay in the loop it will take `n` seconds to load the page, and I am putting `Now()` on each line to see when that loop executing (proving the wait is working), but I do not see a single line outputted during the script's execution.

```
<%
Dim IsBuffer ' this allows easy toggling of the buffer feature
    IsBuffer = False
If IsBuffer Then Response.Buffer = True End If
Server.ScriptTimeout=7200  ' 2 hours (yes this is overkill!!)

i = 0
Response.Write "<h2>Test Page</h2><hr>"
If IsBuffer Then Response.Flush() End If ' flush the header

while i < 20
    i = i + 1
    Response.Write i & " at: " & Now() & "<br />" & VbCrLf
    If IsBuffer Then Response.Flush() End If
    Call asp_Wait(1000) ' milliseconds  
wend

Response.Write "<br /><strong>**TOTAL OF " & i & " LOOPS.**</strong><br />" & vbCrLf

Sub asp_Wait(nMilliseconds)
  Dim oShell
  Set oShell= Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Call oShell.run("ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w " & nMilliseconds,1,TRUE)
End Sub
%>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the default configuration for IIS7 enables GZIP compression. With compression enabled, ASP tends to ignore `Response.Flush()` statements.

Try following the instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to disable compression and see if that helps.

**Edit:** Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11346933/2237785) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I like to let the client handle delays by using redirect to a page that looks like this:

```
<%
ID_template= request.querystring("ID_template")
s_resume=request.querystring("resume")
s_file = "admin_email_send_go.asp?ID_template=" & ID_template
if (s_resume="yes") then s_file = "admin_email_send_resume.asp?ID_template=" & ID_template
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<%=int(session("n_records")/50)%>; url=<%=s_file%>">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function delayer(){
    document.location = "<%=s_file%>"
    }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()',<%=int(session("n_records")*20)%>)" bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
<br>
<table width='100%' height='100%'>
<tr>
<td valign=middle align=center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Total list size: <%=session("n_records")%><br>
        Sent so far: <%=session("n_records_sent")%>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <br>
    Sending next group of <%=application("email_group_size")%> in 2 seconds.<br>
    Please wait...<br>
    <br>
    If you want to quit or pause the process at any time, click <a href='admin_email_send.asp?ID_template=<%=ID_template%>'>here</a>.<br>
    <br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked best for me:

```
<%
Private Function Delay(intSeconds)
    StartTimed = Now()
    CurrentTimed = Now()
    While DateDiff("s",StartTimed,CurrentTimed) < intSeconds
    CurrentTimed = Now()
    Wend
End Function

Response.Write("This is now<br>")
call Delay(10)
Response.Write("This is 10 seconds later<br>")
%>
```