# ASP.NET Core disable Content-Encoding on individually action responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-accept-encoding

How is it possible to disable the `Content-Encoding` for an **individual controller action** in ASP.NET Core (v1.0.1)

I already tried:

```
public FileResult Index(){
    // 
    HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "";
    return File("~/somefile.txt", "text/plain");
}
```

But still it becomes gzipped.

Is there any ActionFilter to use or can I overwrite the filter similar to the MVC 5 variant posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656970/2106997?